# How to use the while controller and a csv data set config element to iterate through a whole csv file regardless of encountered errors?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In Jmeter, I have a CSV Data Set Config pointing to a csv file containing one column with many table names. I want to iterate the whole list until the end of the file and execute DB queries for each table in the list. I have had success but with only one problem:
When the JDBC Request sampler executes an SQL query against a table which does not exist (for whatever reason) the while loop breaks and the rest of the rows from the file are not generating the needed queries.

[image]

I have a while controller with no condition set and underneath it a CSV Data Set Config where I point to a csv file storing a lot of names under just one column: TableName.

I also have a JDBC Request element which makes a query with whatever values goes into the {query} variable.
This query variable is populated by a pre-processor:

```
// Read the value from the CSV Data Set Config
def tableName = vars.get("tableName");
log.info("Target table name:" + tableName)

// Replace the placeholder in the query with the table name from the current iteration of the CSV file
String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + tableName + ";" ;

vars.put("query", query);

log.info("Target query:" + query )
```

And I have a postprocessor which helps me store the table names and counts made in the JDBC Request element into a LinkedList which I print outside of the loop.

My problem is that if one of the tables in the list does not exist, the JDBC Request sampler logs an error and the while loop is broken:

Example eror:
ERROR: relation "schema.tablename" does not exist,
Position: 22

So I need a way to loop through all the CSV file's contents up to the end of the file and not stop when the JDBC Request in the While loop encounters an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is replacing the While Controller with the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).

You can use the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the Loop Count:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```

this way the Loop Controller will iterate as many times as there are lines in your CSV file, not more, not less.

Also double check your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings and ensure that the "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" is set to `Continue`

[image]